# Dependency management tool for Git and CloudFormation?

Tags: git, docker, aws-cloudformation, dependency-management

I am not sure if this is a right community for this type of question but nothing better comes to my mind. Anyway, I have a quite generic question regarding organization of project running with CloudFormation and ECS.

Basically I am building relatively complex architecture with multiple "modules" that can be combined in various ways. Each of such modules contains a few elements:

1. Application source code (usually PHP but not always)
2. Docker images to run application
3. Docker-compose file defining how to run this app for local development
4. CloudFormation template that deploys ECS Service with application

Everything is collected with some scripting, bitbucket pipeline and stuff. For instance local execution run `docker-compose -f module1 -f module2 ... config > docker-compose.yml`, bitbucket pipeline runs similar stuff with multiple services (I will add nested stacks here at some point).

Now, depending on exact project there might be different configuration of such modules.

The question is: do you know any dependency management tool that could help here? I have a feeling that git submodules might be not enough...

Comment: Not sure I understood how docker affects the question. If the question is only about cloudformation dependency management, then [stack-assembly](https://github.com/molecule-man/stack-assembly) or similar tool could help organize templates synced via submodules.

Comment: Well, there would be actually two types setups: for local development using docker-compose and test/prod using CloudFormation with ECS. The tool should be able to handle both in fact...